# Print the counter given as an argument

Tags: counters, expansion

I have a `counterA` and a `counterB`. I want to define a command `\PrintCounter`, which gets either `A` or `B` as argument, and then prints the value of the corresponding counter.

I wrote the following code:

```
\newcommand{\PrintCounter}[1]{
    \thecounter#1
}
```

which results in an error. I need a way to tell LaTeX to evaluate `counter#1` before evaluating `\the`. Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work using `\expandafter`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `\counterA` and `\counterB` are `\count` registers, i.e. TeX counters, then you can use `\csname ..\endcsname` together with `\expandafter`:

```
\newcommand{\PrintCounter}[1]{%
    \expandafter\the\csname counter#1\endcsname
}
```

If they are however defined using `\newcounter`, i.e. LaTeX counters, then
simply use `\arabic{counter#1}`.