# Print counter received as argument

Tags: counters, expansion, arguments

I'm trying to print a counter whose name I receive in the argument `#1`. I tried `\the#1`, which doesn't work and also tried [the solution given in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54026), which gives me the error "You can't use \let after \the".

Is there any way I can do what I want?

Here's an example of what I want:

```
\newcommand{\printcounter}[1]{\expandafter\the\csname #1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\printcounter{section} % this doesn't work
```

Comment: `\expandafter\the#1`?

Comment: @Bernard: That tells me "You can't use 'the letter t' after \the"

Comment: Could you post a full code, that we can play with?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "counter". `\csname the#1\endcsname` could work. If not make a *complete* example

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: A counter, like `section`, `subsection`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the abstract numeric value:

```
\newcommand{\printcounter}[1]{\the\value{#1}}
```

and

```
\printcounter{section}
```

If you want the representation,

```
\thesection
```

or, for a generic interface

```
\newcommand{\printcounter}{\csname the#1\endcsname}

\printcounter{section}
```

What's the difference? Under standard settings, if we are at section 2, subsection 3, the first `\printcounter{subsection}` would print 3, the second one would print 2.3 (the current representation). Take your pick.